# Plotting every 15th element of a vector

Tags: matlab, plot

I have this vector file which is 345*1 and I only want to plot every 15th element versus time.

I tried this:

```
plot(ASCM_time(1:15:end),ASCM_GPS_number_satellite,'g')
```

but it doent work, and it tells me

> Error using plot Vectors must be the same lengths.

Both vectors are 345*1.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely your second vector also needs to be indexed as `ASCM_GPS_number_satellite(1:15:end)`.

So the entire corrected plot statement would be:

`plot(ASCM_time(1:15:end),ASCM_GPS_number_satellite(1:15:end),'g')`

As your code stands you are trying to plot 23 elements in the first vector against 345 elements in the second vector resulting in the error message you described.